# C++: Losing access to memebers of a child class when converting child into the parent

Tags: c++, inheritance, parent

First of all this is my first post so please be gentle. :)

I have a question (perhaps quite basic) but its quite specific and I couldn't find anything that would answer it.

I have created a `Shader` class that is a parent of a `FacingRatioShader` class. In the main.cpp I create an instance of a `FacingRatioShader` class and I pass it as a argument to an `Object::addShader(Shader _shaderType)` method:

```
void Object::addShader(Shader &_shaderType)
{
    m_shaderType = _shaderType;
}
```

And in the header of Object:

```
Shader m_shaderType;
```

The problem is that once the `m_shaderType` has been set it becomes a `Shader` type instead of `FacingRatioShader` type. Because of this I am loosing the ability to access the `FacingRatioShader` specific method called `compute()`.

Is there anyway of creating the type for `m_shaderType` and modifying `Object::addShader` so that it can accept any child of a `Shader` class but still keeping the possibility to access the child methods?

I hope that my question is clear enough. If not please do not hesitate to ask me for more details.

Thanks in advance!

Regads,
Dawid

Comment: If `addShader` accesses a `FacingRatioShader` method, what happens when you pass it a `Shader` that is not a `FacingRatioShader`?

Comment: Well, so far the `FacingRationShader` is the only childe of `Shader` but I am planning to add more. But to answer your question, I have a test `calculate()` method in `Shader` as well just to check it's working.

Comment: Any subtype of Shader (now and future) can be treated as a Shader (if it continues to behave as one) and so can be substituted. But you lose type information when you pass in the _shaderType argument and so can't know what dynamic type it is (without casting).

Comment: Yeah, that is what I though its happening. The only thing is that I don't know how to have a dynamic type for the member `m_shaderType` cause making it `Shader` type seems to transform it to `Shader` from `FacingRatioShader`.

Comment: In your method declaration you're saying 'Here I'm passing in a Shader'. All your method can know is it can do Shader operations (but they can be *performed* differently depending on the subtype; unknown to your method). Yes if you like it is 'transformed' to the supertype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is **partly yes, and partly no**. You can change `m_shaderType` to store a **pointer**, but you will still only be able to call methods that are declared inside the parent class (so in `Shader`).

If you want to call methods dependant on the class/subclass, declare them in the base class as `virtual` and overwrite their bodies inside child classes.

```
class Object{
   Shader* m_shaderType;
   // ...
   void addShader(Shader &_shaderType)
   {
      m_shaderType = &_shaderType;
   }
   // ...
};
```

You could - theoretically - store information about what type did you pass to `addShader` (with an additional variable that you would set accordingly to recognize the child classes), but that's not a really good idea.

Comment: Thanks Paweł. I have tried to make it a virtual function but I don't think it worked (maybe I was doing something wrong). It is still accessing the `Shader::calculate` instead of `FacingRatioShader::calculate`.

Comment: You still need to store the value in a __pointer__ in your class. And - in case you're not sure - the word `virtual` should be added to `Shader::calculate`. And of course both methods should have same arguments and same return value.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already mentioned, you need a polimorphic datatype, and pass the object pointers. In fact passing by value you are performing a *slicing* operation: all information of the child type are lost when copying to an object of the base type.

Furthermore directly answering your question, the correct way for a base class to invoke the method in a child - that note, is not recommended, but sometimes it can be needed - is with dynamic_cast:

```
class Shader {
    ...
};

class FacingRatioShader : public Shader {
    ...
public:
    void Compute();
};
```

A user of these classes, like your `Object` class, can do this:

```
Shader *shader = CreateShader(); // no detail for this factory in this example
FacingRatioShader *fr_shader = dynamic_cast<FacingRatioShader*>shader;
if (fr_shader) {
    // non-zero only if shader is a FacingRatioShader. Note: you need at least one virtual
    // method to use it, if not compute() itself, the destructor, typically.
    fr_shader->Compute();
}
```

On the other side, being `Compute()` a method that I could expect in *any shader* of your hierarchy, I would say that your `Shader` be an interface. Declaring that *any shader must have compute()* can be done with abstract method declaration. So it could be:

```
class Shader {
    ...
public:
    virtual void Compute()=0;
};

class FacingRatioShader : public Shader {
    ...
public:
    void Compute();
};
```

In this case you cannot create instances of `Shader`, but pointers are still legal so the user code will be just:

```
Shader *shader = CreateShader(); // no detail for this factory in this example
shader->Compute();
```

Comment: Alternately, you can have `void Shader::Compute() {}`: if a subclass doesn't override `Compute()`, that just means it has no effect.

Comment: @aschepler I would expect Compute() actually compute the shader, and be an error to not-to-compute when invoking Compute()... so given the few information from the OP in this case I wouldn't do it. But yes, generally speaking it's an option, especially *when the default action is admissible and is do-nothing*

Answer (score 0):

It is still a `FacingRatioShader`, but you're looking at it as if it's a `Shader` and so only `Shader` "stuff" is available. You could use a cast to look at it as the child type.

Pseudo code only. Big problem is dynamic cast on references won't work. You need to use pointers so you can get a null pointer if the shader isn't actually a `FacingRatioShader`

```
FacingRatioShader *frs = dynamic_cast<FacingRatioShader*>(&obj.m_shaderType);
if (frs != 0) {
    frs->somefacingRatioShaderMethod();
}
```

< edit > Should point out that in most cases, needing to do this is an indication that your design / class breakdown is wrong...

Comment: Hi John3136, first of all thank you for you quick reply. To be honest I am not sure yet if I understand your example but I will try it and let you know how it went. One question though what `dynamic_cast` mean?

Comment: @dawid You really should Google it. John3136 as you know it will work on references but it will throw an exception instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to thank you all guys for you help! In the end I made the `compute()` a virtual function. As I mentioned I have tried this before but the thing I was doing wrong was the fact I would create a `Shader m_shaderType` instead of a pointer `Shader *m_shaderType`.

I am glad I didn't have to use the dynamic_cast as it seems more complex and might indicate a wrong class design as mentioned by John3136. :)

Thanks again for quick and very helpful answers. It makes me think I should revisit my basic knowledge about pointers and references.